# failed to run npm i with node-gyp errors

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

i am trying to do npm i --force and this all fails with below error

```
pm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_trace.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz_registry.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/connected_channel.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker_registry.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/status_util.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_args.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_internal.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/message_compress.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_gzip.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_identity.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.o
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.20.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.23.3 and node@16.20.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.20.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.20.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/moblizeit/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.20.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/moblizeit/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.20.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/moblizeit/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.20.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.20.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.cc:284:5: error: suspicious concatenation of string literals in an array initialization; did you mean to separate the elements with a comma? [-Werror,-Wstring-concatenation]
npm ERR!     "requested the incoming call",
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.cc:283:5: note: place parentheses around the string literal to silence warning
npm ERR!     "How many completion queues were checked looking for a CQ that had "
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:201:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/bin/node" "/Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/moblizeit/GitHub/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/admin/businesscardadmin/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/moblizeit/.npm/_logs/2023-05-20T13_11_17_572Z-debug-0.log
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "businesscardadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "angular-gridster2": "^8.2.0",
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^3.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "firebaseui": "^4.2.0",
    "firebaseui-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-org-chart": "^1.1.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.2",
    "forcejs": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

Comment: try to  remove package-lock.json and/or yarn.lock 

after removing these files, ran:

npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an indirect dependency on the `grpc` package, which is deprecated and is not compatible with recent versions of Node. You are probably getting this dependency through the `firebase` package. You have a dependency on version 7.x, but the latest release is version 9.22.0. Upgrading that dependency will probably fix this error.